# Importing jquery with JSPM in Aurelia app. Build errors

Tags: jquery, npm, gulp, aurelia, jspm

Could anyone help me solve my build errors. Trying to build aurelia app with gulp. But importing jquery doesn't work straight away.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

gives me an error

> src\examples\datatablesExample.ts(1,8): error TS1192: Module '"jquery"' has no default export.
>
> typings\jquery\jquery.d.ts(3210,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '$' must be of type 'cssSelectorHelper', but here has type 'JQueryStatic'.

So I'm importing jquery as follows

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Can anyone explain why some guys can import jquery straight away, but I can't? Also what is the second error about, is it something jquery has mixed up?

Just trying to figure out jspm with aurelia, jquery and other modules.

Comment: It seems that the jquery file is not exporting anything. How did you install it?

Comment: @FabioLuz jspm install jquery

Comment: Are you using the skeleton project? Jquery is installed automatically when you run `jspm install -y`, there's no need to install it twice

Comment: Yes, it was skeleton project. 
Tried different installations etc. But still get the second error.

Comment: Download the latest version of the skeleton project. run `npm install` `jspm install -y`. Then, you just have to import jquery `import $ from 'jquery'`. There's no need to install jquery through jspm

Answer (score 1):

after you have installed jquery by

```
 jspm install jquery
```

try to load jquery by

```
import 'jquery';
```

But ensure that you are in root dir of your project when you execute the jspm command.
After installing i would suggest to make a clean and a gulp build command again before you use the methods.

Comment: Thanks, works the same as import * as $ from 'jquery';

Answer (score 0):

To fix `'"jquery"' has no default export`, I added this line to tsconfig.json:

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```